# SQL Server Management Studio: Object Explorer doesn't show Tables

Tags: ssms

I have a LocalDB running and I can log in to it via SQL Server Management Studio. I've granted my user db_datareader and other roles, but the Object Explorer tree still does not list Tables under Databases > System Databases > master.

I can create tables and select, etc. They show up in information_schema.tables with "master" as the table catalog. I created a view and it does show up under Views, so the issue seems to be limited to tables.

I don't know what else to try - any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try one press on the name of the database , and then press the refresh circle line on the top of the object explorer. may be now it will work. you can see picture added.

[image]